# Excel VBA sort by date

Tags: excel, vba

Working on a Search/Filter userform, and I am having problems when trying to filter dates.

When I compare a date to determine if it contains a string, it seems to work just fine (I believe I cast it as a string during the compare, fwiw).  When it comes time to filter by the date column though, it doesn't recognize the rows that contain the given string and removes everything from the sheet.

Example:

Filter string: 6/ (by default, wildcards (*) are placed on each side)

```
Date entries: 6/15/1956
              4/3/1971
              10/13/1960
              2/16/1983
```

I want lines 1 and 4 to be shown, since they contain "6/"

I realize that the date object is actually an array of sorts; is this why I am having issues?  Can I not do what I want to here with a normal autofilter?  Do I need to make a special case when sorting by the date column, and will this apply for other data types (money, time, etc.)?

Thanks

Filter code for reference (if variables aren't declared, they are either global or junk-variables)

```
Private Sub Filter_CommandButton_Click()
    'Filters by a text input and a column to filter
    Dim isInCol As Boolean
    Dim sortKey As String
    Dim sortOrder As XlSortOrder
    Dim currentData As Range
    Dim sortField As Integer ' This is the offset, determined by list index

    If filterColumn Is Nothing Then
        gojira = MsgBox("You need to enter a column to filter", vbOKOnly)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' setting active sheet complete data
    Set currentData = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    ' make sort key a wildcard
    If include = True Then
        sortKey = "*" & filterText & "*"
    Else ' for excluding the entered text
        sortKey = "<>" & "*" & filterText & "*"
    End If

    ' find list index for sorting
    sortField = Me.ColumnFilter_ComboBox.ListIndex + 1

    ' populate sort order with value of Ascend/Descend options.
    If descend Then
        sortOrder = xlDescending
    Else
        sortOrder = xlAscending
    End If

    ' Search column to see if text exists
    isInCol = False
    For Each foo In filterColumn
        If caseSense Then
            If InStr(foo.Value, filterText) Then ' > 0 Then
                isInCol = True
                Exit For
            End If
        ElseIf Not caseSense Then
            If InStr(LCase(foo.Value), LCase(filterText)) Then
                isInCol = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next foo

    If isInCol Then ' filter the table by the selected col; Use Range Sort
        With ActiveSheet
            currentData.AutoFilter Field:=sortField, Criteria1:=sortKey, VisibleDropDown:=False
            currentData.Sort key1:=filterColumn, Order1:=sortOrder, Header:=xlYes
        End With
    End If

    blah = bleh
End Sub
```

Comment: I think the problem is that if your dates are really formatted as dates in your table. Which means that they are stored as numbers. So `6/15/1956` is being stored as `20621`. And if that is the case, you will never find `6/` in the date.

Comment: Yes, they are formatted as dates.  So it sounds like I am SOL. If there are no other options, then thanks for trying.

Comment: If you are able to create a helper column then you could still make it work. The helper column could be something as easy as `="_"&B2` (if B2 is where the date is) and copy it down. Then you could perform the action you are describing on the helper column.

Comment: @guitarthrower So that worked; I just did this: `=IF(D2<>"",TEXT(D2, "mm/dd/yyyy"), "")` and it worked fine. Problem now is that I don't want to show the helper in the combobox, but when I make a non-contiguous range, the combobox only shows `$A$1:$D$1` rather than `$A$1:$D$1,$E$1:$L$1`. Any idea how to deal with this, or is it the topic of another question?

Comment: I'm glad I (partially!) helped. I think this second issue would be better served in a separate question.

Comment: Also, you should put your answer below as the answer, so others know what worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @guitarthrower, this is what I found:

A cell formatted in DATE format cannot be compared to a string.  Creating a helper column next to it and casting it as a string/text object allows one to compare a search string to that.

Here is the formula that worked:

```
=IF(D2<>"",TEXT(D2, "mm/dd/yyyy"), "")
```

This made a column of values that one could search through by a string, i.e. "/06/" to find any dates on the sixth of the month.  I used the IF construct so it only populated the cell if it wasn't blank.

I'm adding it to the wiki, and the community can make any corrections necessary.